# TSQL - populate record from the next adjacent row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Current Output

```
Activity            FromTime                ToTime
-------------------------------------------------------------------
STOPPED INSIDE POI  2012-11-14 01:08:46.000 2012-11-14 01:19:46.000
MOVING INSIDE POI   2012-11-14 01:20:46.000 2012-11-14 01:21:46.000
MOVING OUTSIDE POI  2012-11-14 01:22:46.000 2012-11-14 01:22:46.000
STOPPED OUTSIDE POI 2012-11-14 01:23:46.000 2012-11-14 01:23:46.000
MOVING OUTSIDE POI  2012-11-14 01:24:46.000 2012-11-14 01:25:46.000
```

Expected Output

```
Activity            FromTime                ToTime
-------------------------------------------------------------------
STOPPED INSIDE POI  2012-11-14 01:08:46.000 2012-11-14 01:20:46.000
MOVING INSIDE POI   2012-11-14 01:20:46.000 2012-11-14 01:22:46.000
MOVING OUTSIDE POI  2012-11-14 01:22:46.000 2012-11-14 01:23:46.000
STOPPED OUTSIDE POI 2012-11-14 01:23:46.000 2012-11-14 01:24:46.000
MOVING OUTSIDE POI  2012-11-14 01:24:46.000 2012-11-14 01:25:46.000
```

Any easy way of doing this?

Comment: Can you provide table and column names?  And is there a primary key or other sort order being used here?

Comment: Added column name headers @ PinnyM

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @Mihir - That's a shame. `LAG` and `LEAD` are 2012 features and could have been handy there.

Comment: Agree @ Martin, LAG/LEAD is an awesome feature added to 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
UPDATE table1
SET ToTime = join_table.newToTime
FROM (
  SELECT t2.FromTime target, MIN(t1.FromTime) newToTime 
  FROM table1 t1 
  JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.FromTime > t2.FromTime
  GROUP BY t2.FromTime) join_table
WHERE FromTime = join_table.target
```

Basically you're looking for the minimum `FromTime` that is greater than the current row - and use that as the new value for `ToTime`.  Note that the last row will not be updated, since no matching greater `FromTime` will be found.

Comment: Super@Pinny That's what I was trying to do with the select. But updating the temp table before selecting made my life easier. Thanks!

Comment: In case of 2 same FromNights (of course it is not mentioned that this could happen) this version will return errored results as it will have for both of them the same ToTime which will be the first different time after all of the same. T-clausen's version in that case will fetch the right results! So, I think t-clausens version is the right answer.

Comment: In such a situation, it's not clear that those would be 'errored results' - it depends on the intended usage of the ToTime column.  And  as there's no defined sort order for duplicate FromTime entries, one could argue that t-clausen's results would be unpredictable in such a case.  The solutions offered are based on the context required, not on abstract possibilities that wouldn't make sense in this context.

Answer (score 1):

```
;with a as
(
select Activity, FromTime, ToTime, 
row_number() over (order by FromTime) rn from <yourtable>
)
select a.Activity, a.FromTime, coalesce(b.FromTime, a.ToTime) ToTime
from a left join a b on a.rn = b.rn - 1
order by a.rn
```

Comment: Thanks @ t-clausen, I got the idea but it's a little bit more work for me to go this way at this point, I am running short of time right now. But, I will try this solution soon and let everyone know. Thanks again for your help.